# How to setup a fixture for a group of tests in clojure.test

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, clojure-testing

In my tests I use something like:

```
;; api.utils
(defn wrap-test-server [f]
  (start-test-server)
  (f)
  (stop-test-server))

;; api.some-endpoint
(use-fixtures
  :once
  utils/wrap-test-server)
```

However, I have to duplicate the fixture setup code in every test module.

How can I setup a global fixture for all the tests?
Or even better, for a "package" so that tests in `api.*` are wrapped with the start / stop fixture.

Note that in this case, I don't care about the wrapping "level". The following would both work:

```
;; Wrap around all the tests in the package:
(start-test-server)
(test-1)
...
(test-n)
(stop-test-server)
;; Wrap every test in the package:
(start-test-server)
(test-1)
(stop-test-server)
...
(start-test-server)
(test-n)
(stop-test-server)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely pull that function into another namespace and re-use it that way and do something like this:

```
(defn one-time-setup [f]
    (start-test-server)
    (f)
    (stop-test-server))

(use-fixtures :once one-time-setup)
```

This blog [post](http://thornydev.blogspot.nl/2012/09/before-and-after-logic-in-clojuretest.html) summarizes it pretty well. From the post:

> A `:once` fixture - method that will be called before any tests are run
>   and it will be passed a function to call that will invoke all the
>   tests.

Comment: True, that's what I do already. I updated the question to make it clearer, thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'm not sure there's a way to avoid that one-liner in each namespace. You might be able to do something programmatic with namespaces but that seems like a bad trade-off for complexity.